# Is it possible to read a multi word table in a SQLalchemy Table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a project where a need to read a very old Microsoft Access database. In this mdb there are multiple tables with a 2 word named table f.e  Question Table1;  Question Table2

I've seen the 2h video about sqlachemy 2.0, the package works amazing and is exactly what I need, so I thought to give that approach a shot
I'm trying to reflect the table as a python object

The problem is that the table has 2 words ("Question Table")

```
engine = create_engine(connectionstring, future=True)

meta = MetaData()
with engine.begin() as conn:
    questiontable =  Table("Question Table1", meta, autoload_with=conn)
```

This script was working on a single named Table but with a multi word it throws a KeyError: 'VARBINARY'

Is it somehow possible to read this table with SQLalchemy

Just wanted to mention that I am not allowed to rename the table (because there is a parser that would break when I do so)

Hopefully someone can help me out,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `Table("[Question Table1]", meta, autoload_with=conn)`?

Comment: Hi, I tried that, unfortunately it gives an error
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: [Question Table1]